# Remove Flip Over Hover Image

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to remove the effect of flipping the product image when hovering over it, as you can see it here on [my site.](http://test.italsapori.ch/product-category/italien/)

I really hope this can get achieved somehow.

Thanks a lot for your help. Appreciate it a lot, since I couldn't find the answer myself.

Comment: You mean the black layout on it (Product)?

Answer (score 0):

It should be solved by adding this CSS to your theme:

```
.mkdf-woo-no-space.mkdf-woo-pl-info-predefined ul.products>.product .mkdf-pl-inner .mkdf-pl-text {
    display: none;
}
```

For link on the whole product card is the next CSS required:

```
.mkdf-product-list-title > a {
    padding-top: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend. It did work.  But now the image itself isn't a link to the product. Do you know how I can fix this?
http://test.italsapori.ch/product-category/italien/

Comment: I made an edit. If it's working, please mark my answer as correct.